# Check JSON data type using jq

Tags: json, bash, types, jq

I'm trying to check the actual data type of a JSON value belonging to a specific key.

`test.json`

```
{
    "id": 50,
    "name": "Joe"
}
```

I want something analogous to this:

```
$ `jq 'typeof("id")' < test.json`
(output)>> string
```

Is this possible using `jq`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `type`:

```
jq -r '[1.23,"abc",true,[],{},null][]| type' <<< '""'
number
string
boolean
array
object
null
```

In your example you could check:

```
jq '.id|type=="number"' file.json
```

Or use it in a `select` filter to display those ids which are **not** numbers for example:

```
jq '.[]|select(id|type=="number"|not)' file.json
```

Comment: glad to hear that

Comment: Note that there are [builtins](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#arrays,objects,iterables,booleans,numbers,normals,finites,strings,nulls,values,scalars) that filter the various types. So instead of `.id|type=="number"`, you could simply do `.id|numbers` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `type` function in order to get the value type as a string.

Example: https://jqplay.org/jq?q=map(type)&j=%5B0%2C%20false%2C%20%5B%5D%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20null%2C%20%22hello%22%5D